# Can C# use attribute to get return data from methods inside controllers and services?

Tags: c#

Currently using asp core to build a web service system

I hope to obtain the return data of the service method in a specific controller through attribute

The following are examples

```
    [HttpPost, Route("list")]
    [CustomAttribute]
    public IActionResult GetList([FromBody] NewsClassDto request)
    {
      
        var data = newsClassService.GetList(model);

        return OkResponse(data);
    }
```

NewsClassService  Examples

```
    public NewsClassDto GetList(NewsClassDto dto)
    {


        var daoClassData = _newsClassDao.GetList(dto);

        var daoData = _newsDataDao.GetList(dto);

        /** logical processing **/

        return daoClassData;
        
    }
```

I want to record through

```
[CustomAttribute] 
newsClassService.GetList(model);
```

data returns content and

```
_newsClassDao.GetList(dto); 
_newsDataDao.GetList(dto);
```

daoClassData returns content and daoData  returns content , but I don't know how to implement this in Attribute

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is very common.  What you need to do is create an action filter attribute.  You can read about filters in general [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;

namespace aspnet6test;

public class CustomFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext context)
    {
        if (context.Result is OkObjectResult okResult)
        {
            // Here, okResult.Value will contain the result data.  You'll have to 
            // explore with a series of IF statements whether or not is the data you're 
            // looking for.  Example:
            if (okResult.Value is List<SomeDto> listOfDtos)
            {
                // So it is a list of wanted SomeDto objects.  Do your magic.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above example runs the code after the result has been returned by the controller action, which I believe satisfies the requirements in your question.

It would be used like this:

```cs
    [HttpPost("list")] // <-- The HTTP verp attributes are also Route attributes
    [CustomFilter]
    public IActionResult GetList([FromBody] NewsClassDto request)
    {
      
        var data = newsClassService.GetList(model);

        return Ok(data); // <-- I believe this is the correct way.
    }
```

The filter may accept properties and even constructor values, but that's [another topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/).

Comment: It seems that only the content of OkObjectResult can be obtained

Comment: Thanks!! Can I also get 
newsClassService.GetList(model) 
in OnResultExecuted in 
var daoData = _newsClassDao.GetList(dto);
What about the data returned by daoData?

Comment: As stated, `okResult.Value` contains the result of the call you made to `GetList`.  Debug and verify for yourself.

Comment: Sorry, I have corrected the content of the problem, `okResult.Value` does have the content of `GetList (daoClassData)` , but there is no content returned by `daoData (_newsDataDao.GetList(dto)` ;